# Как получить случайную строку из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Как сделать вывод рандомной строки из файла?

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
import random

with open("something.txt") as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

random_line = random.choice(lines).strip()
```

(Я предпологаю, что вывод строки `random_line` уже нет для вас проблема.)

---

*Объяснение:*

- Метод `readlines()` читает отдельные строки файла в список (включая `"\n"` в конце всякой строки),
- функция `choice()` выберет случайный элемент—строку из этого списка и
- метод `.strip()` удалит праздные знаки с начала и конца строки, в том числе и символ конца строки `"\n"`.

Когда бы вы хотели удалить *только символ конца строки*, используйте

```
random_line = random.choice(lines)[:-1]
```

вместо последней строки.

Comment: А как быть с файлами, которые не поместятся в оперативку? Хотя... Какой вопрос, такой ответ. Вероятно, нужно просто лабораторку сдать и забыть, простите за прямоту...