# Почему переменная content возвращает один символ D?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот что лежит в текстовике

```
D:/Dev program/регистрация и настройки тест/application.py
```

Вот код:

```
index=1
def read_path(index):
    file=open('setAphinePath.txt','r')
    content=file.readline(index)
    print(content)
    file.close()
    return content
```

Comment: а что вы хотите получить в переменной `content` ?

Comment: в переменной content должна быть строка соответствующая индексу ну например 1 - первая сторка 2- вторая сторка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы наверно хотели читать строку файла с номером определённым в параметре `index`.

Строки файла определены символом `'\n'` (переход на новую строку) в конце каждой строки.

Метод `.readline()` читает *очередную* строку (начиная с первой строки файла).

Параметр в методе `.readline()` может только *прекратить ввод строки* после заданного количества символов (и вы задали **один**).

Нужно это сделать по другому — читать и *пропускать* строки с начала файла, пока не встречается строка с номером в параметре `index`. Например так:

```
def read_path(index):
    file=open('setAphinePath.txt')    # 'r' не нужно
    for __ in range(index - 1):       # __  значит, что имя переменной не важно
        file.readline()               # читаем, но не сохраняем
    content = file.readline()         # теперь уже строку сохраним - в переменной content
    file.close()
    # print(content)                  # это не нужно, но может выть для тестирования
    return content
```

Другой подход вы можете перенять [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1087021/233990).

*Примечание:*

Я предполагал, что вы номеруете строки файла с `1`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в `file.readline()` с какой-то целью передается `index` который равен 1, при передаче параметра в `readline()` он будет читать только указанное в параметре количество байт.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
index = 1

def read_path(index):    
    with open("setAphinePath.txt") as f:
        while index:
            content = f.readline()
            index -= 1
        return content

print(read_path(index)) 
print(read_path(2))
print(read_path(999))
```